# Oracle rows To Column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Old Result

```
Column_Name
A
B
C
D
```

New Required Result

```
Column_Name
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
```

Restrictions, (Count is unknown. Could be A, B, C or A, B, C, D, E and so on.

Comment: A SQL query returns a result set with a fixed number of defined columns.  You can do this, but it requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you are looking for each row to be its own column, @GordonLinoff is correct. If you are looking to simply aggregate the values into a single field, `LISTAGG` may work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to make a list of all the values in a certain column behind each other you can use `LISTAGG`. 
For example:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(Column_Name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Column_Name) "Column_Listing"
FROM TableA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your question literally, you have a query returning a single column with a variable number of rows, say

```
select 'A' column_name from dual union all
select 'B' column_name from dual union all
select 'C' column_name from dual union all
select 'D' column_name from dual
```

and you need to have the result in a single row with a single column containing the concatenation of the values returned by the original query, wrapped by `''`; in your example, you need:

```
Column_Name
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
```

If this is correct, you may simply need [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/LISTAGG.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
select listagg('''' || column_name || '''', ', ') within group ( order by column_name)
from (
        select 'A' column_name from dual union all
        select 'B' column_name from dual union all
        select 'C' column_name from dual union all
        select 'D' column_name from dual 
     ) yourQuery
```